# converting a list to a map, Why does DART ask you not to use the Map.fromIterable method?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, dictionary

```
// Convert a list to a map type.
test() {
  var y = [
    [10, 20],
    [30, 43],
    [51, 60]
  ];
  var mapOne = Map.fromIterable(y, key: (v) => v[0], value: (v) => v[1]);
  var mapTwo = {for (final x in y) x[0]: x[1]};
  print(mapOne); //outputs {10: 20, 30: 43, 51: 60}
  print(mapTwo); //outputs {10: 20, 30: 43, 51: 60}
}
```

As you can see from the above code, both syntaxes result in same output, yet dart gives you a warning saying

```
prefer for elements when building maps from iterables
```

So my question is why does dart prefer the syntax of mapTwo over mapOne?

If thats the case whats the point of having methods like Map.fromIterable if dart don't want you using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.fromIterable` existed before the collection elements feature existed. Removing it now would be a breaking change. The warning comes from a lint and not from the language. It's a style preference.

Source: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2521#issuecomment-1257199865

Answer (score 1):

> Using 'for' elements brings several benefits including:
>
> Performance
>
> Flexibility
>
> Readability
>
> Improved type inference
>
> Improved interaction with null safety

See [prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_for_elements_to_map_fromIterable.html) for details.

Comment: Yep from that's where i got the idea to use for loop. My question is basically if Map.fromIterables imethod is so useless why doesn't dart just remove it? just leads to confusion.

Comment: On the other hand introducing breaking change like that wouldn't be possible.